# Shinyproxy & Keycloak - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: docker, shiny, keycloak, shinyproxy

I am learning about Keycloak and ShinyProxy.

I am using Docker. I have a container where Keycloak is working (from Keycloak Docker image) and I have another container where ShinyProxy is working (https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy-config-examples/tree/master/02-containerized-docker-engine).

I tested ShinyProxy (localhost:8180/) using authentication: simple and it was working.

Then I changed application.yml (authentication: keycloak):

---

```
proxy:
  port: 8180
  authentication: keycloak
  admin-groups: admins
  users:
  - name: jack
    password: password
    groups: admins
  - name: jeff
    password: password
  docker:
      internal-networking: true
  specs:
  - id: 01_hello
    display-name: Hello Application3
    description: Application which demonstrates the basics of a Shiny app
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shinyproxy::run_01_hello()"]
    container-image: openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo
    container-network: sp-example-net
  - id: 06_tabsets
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shinyproxy::run_06_tabsets()"]
    container-image: openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo
    container-network: sp-example-net
  - id: anaApp
    display-name: anaApp
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/euler2')"]
    container-image: anaid
    container-network: sp-example-net
  keycloak:
    realm: shinyproxy
    auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080/auth
    resource: shinyproxy
    credentials-secret: 8af5deba-c9f1-4358-881b-3981460aded0


logging:
  file:
    shinyproxy.log
```

I created a realm called shinyproxy and a client called shinyproxy in Keycloak.
I have as a Valid redirect URIs: http://localhost:8180/*

KeyCloak is working in localhost:8080/auth/

Shinyproxy is using port localhost:8180

If I go to localhost:8180/ , I see the Log in page, but after I logged in I got this error: "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

I don't know if the Valid redirect URIs or the auth-server-url is wrong.

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you, 
Ana

Comment: [This](https://support.openanalytics.eu/t/keycloak-ssl-redirect-loop/430) seems to be a related.

Comment: What do the container logs of both Keycloak and ShinyProxy tell you at the moment you try to log in? How did you setup your Docker containers? What network are they in? Are you using `docker-compose`?

Comment: did you figure this out?